# assert error using schema 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd, assertions

I am facing problem in creating a schema if anyone could please assist. I am using Oxygen XML Editor. So the problem is that I have a schema declaration as below:

```
<xs:attribute name="output" type="xs:ID"  use="optional"/>
<xs:assert test="(@output ne 'result') and (@output ne 'isTimedOut')"/>
```

So what the above intends is that some element has an 'output' attribute which is *optional*. But if this attribute is defined, then it cannot have values 'result' or 'isTimedOut' i.e. if in the instance xml I say output="result" then it should not validate. 
Now the problem is that in the xml I cannot have the element without 'output' attribute even though I am declaring it as optional. So if the tag does not define the output attrbute then the xml is not validated because of the assertion. Could anyone please suggest how to have the optional behaviour for this attribute. Below is the error that Oxygen gives:

```
Element task does not satisfy assertion (@output ne 'result') and (@output ne 'isTimedOut')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see that either the output attribute is not present or it is different from the not allowed values:

```
<xs:assert test="
     not(@output) or 
     ((@output ne 'result') and (@output ne 'isTimedOut'))"/>
```

Regards,
George